# In Pandas how can I reduce the rows so that I only accept the row with the first true in every sub group of trues?

Tags: python, pandas

As an example, consider the following:

Input

```
a b   c  bool
1 243 0  true
1 253 1  false
1 267 0  true
1 245 0  true
1 234 0  false
1 255 0  true
1 275 0  true
1 295 0  true
```

I want the output to be the following:

```
a b   c  bool
1 243 0  true
1 253 1  false
1 267 0  true
1 234 0  false
1 255 0  true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some boolean masking for this and do it in one line:

```
df.loc[(df['bool'] != df['bool'].shift(1))]
```

out:

```
>>> df.loc[(df['bool'] != df['bool'].shift(1))]
   a    b  c   bool
0  1  243  0   True
1  1  253  1  False
2  1  267  0   True
4  1  234  0  False
5  1  255  0   True
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df.groupby(df['bool'].ne(True).cumsum()).head(2)
Out[201]: 
   a    b  c   bool
0  1  243  0   True
1  1  253  1  False
2  1  267  0   True
4  1  234  0  False
5  1  255  0   True
```